# This keyword in Binding at React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binding

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addContact = this.addContact.bind(this);
    console.log(this);
}
```

I do not understand that what is the meaning of last 'this' keyword which is in parenthesis. What does it represent? I understand that I should bind when I want use methods. But I am binding what at constructor? I did not send any object or something else to constructor so what happens in there?

I am a newbie self-taught programmer and struggling with this issue. May you help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What represent the `this` inside `bind()` function

`this` corresponding with your code, at your class `App`

If your method `addContact` it's not binding in context of `App` class, you can't make anything with this method.

Perhaps you can convert this method into a static method, if you don't need `this` context into your method.

Please see this example : [MDN EXAMPLE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Glad to have helped you, if it resolved you can marked it please.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code, e.g. in the `render` method you will call this function in some way like `onClick={this.addContact}`.

`this.addContact = this.addContact.bind(this);` code will guarantee that `addContact` function will be called with scope of `this` (`App` instance, not in scope of e.g. `Button` with `onClick` handler).

Comment: It's not fully true, because you don't need an event handler for binding a method. For example: you a method called A and the second called B, this two method are using a binding with `this` context, the method B will be called in method A. 

Perhaps, if you don't bind this two method, you can't called B into A :)

Comment: I agree, 'guarantee' is not a correct word here. But I hope main idea of using .bind(this) is clear.